# read.csv causing invalid multibyte string error

Tags: r

I'm trying to upload a CSV into R, which normally is not an issue for me, but I seem to be having trouble with this file.

When I run:

```
test <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datacfb123/testdata/main/cher_2_current_df_alternative_trunc_final.csv')
```

I get hit with the following sets of errors/warning messages:

```
Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<ff><fe>U'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls
3: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls
4: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls
5: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls
```

What exactly is causing this issue and how can it be fixed?

Comment: What are the column names in your CSV? Are there Latin or other characters in one or more of the column names?

Comment: @JohnPolo - Can you not download the file?

Comment: I checked the file and it is encoded in UCS2 little endian. Try downloading the file and run `test <- read.csv("file.csv",sep="\t", fileEncoding = "UCS-2LE")`

Comment: I generally don't download the files that people share. ... I see that several of the rows have so many words/strings that they span many more columns than there are columns with names. Maybe something to do with that.

Comment: PD. I cant download it because vpn, but you can test `test <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datacfb123/testdata/main/cher_2_current_df_alternative_trunc_final.csv', sep="\t", fileEncoding = "UCS-2LE")`

Comment: I'm glad, please answer yourself so it is answeded ;)